# Compacting returned array

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have an array that comes back from the api as an array object - and I am interested in creating a new array of just the keys. Is there a clean way of doing this than running a map and populating a new array?

Returned Array

```
[ {
  "contactType" : "AUTHORISED_SIGNATORY",
  "contactTypeName" : "Authorised Signatory"
}, {
  "contactType" : "LEGAL_CONTACT",
  "contactTypeName" : "Legal Contact"
}, {
  "contactType" : "PRIMARY_CONTACT",
  "contactTypeName" : "Primary Contact"
} ]
```

New Array

```
["AUTHORISED_SIGNATORY", "LEGAL_CONTACT", "PRIMARY_CONTACT"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is using a `map`:

```js
console.log([ {
  "contactType" : "AUTHORISED_SIGNATORY",
  "contactTypeName" : "Authorised Signatory"
}, {
  "contactType" : "LEGAL_CONTACT",
  "contactTypeName" : "Legal Contact"
}, {
  "contactType" : "PRIMARY_CONTACT",
  "contactTypeName" : "Primary Contact"
} ].map(e => e.contactType));
```